# Requested URL not found on the server in XAMPP using laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I tried to edit and updated the employee info, unfortunately, it doesn't work
I fetch the employee id but when I sent the updated data it's not working.
it shows Requested URL not found on the server

this is my controller

```
public function edit_function($id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('employee.empedit')->with('user',$user);
}

public function update(Request $request,$id){

    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->phonenumber = $request->input('phonenumber');
    $user->profession = $request->input('profession');

    if($request->hasfile('images')){
        $file= $request->file('images');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/user/', $filename);
        $user->images= $filename;

    }
    $user->save();
    return redirect('empprofile')->with('success', 'Data Updated.');
}
```

this is my view

```
<form method="post" action="/updateimages/{{ $user->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Update The Information Of Employee</h2>

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label >Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }} ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }} ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phonenumber" value="{{ $user->phonenumber }} ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Profession :</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profession" placeholder="Enter Profession" name="profession" value="{{ $user->profession }} ">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Image :</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="images" placeholder="" name="images" value="{{ $user->images }}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" style="width:50%;">Update Data</button>
                    </div>




        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('edit_profile/{id}' , "empController@edit_function");

Route::put('/updateimages/{id}', "empController@update");
```

it shows Requested URL not found on the server

Comment: Did you try remake the router's cache (`php artisan route:cache`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not a Big fan of Url and id  So i will go with

**name based routing and Route Model Binding**

> Step 1: Refactor Routes

```
Route::get('edit_profile/{user}' , "empController@edit_function")
     ->name('user.editProfile');

Route::put('/updateimages/{user}', "empController@update")
     ->name('user.updateProfile');
```

> Step 2: Refactor Controller Method

```
public function edit_function(User $user)
{
    $user = $user;
    return view('employee.empedit')->with('user',$user);
}

public function update(Request $request,User $user)
{

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->phonenumber = $request->input('phonenumber');
    $user->profession = $request->input('profession');

    if($request->hasfile('images')){
        $file= $request->file('images');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/user/', $filename);
        $user->images= $filename;

    }
    $user->save();
    return redirect('empprofile')->with('success', 'Data Updated.');
}
```

> Step 3: Edit Html and Switch to route helper

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.updateProfile',['user' => $user])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Kindly Comment Below if you are facing any issues

Answer (score 0):

Its because some other route replce your existing route. You can solve it by debugging. it will cost your time. I had a better solution, 
You name your route. and call the route by `route()` function.

From your above information,

It may be,

in route ->

```
Route::put('/updateimages/{id}', "empController@update")->name('updateImage');
```

in view (form action) ->

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('updateImage', $user->id ) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```